# Replacing a mapping for tests

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have all my NHibernate in one assembly and that assembly gets loaded into my NHibernate session for my app and that works great.  For my test project though I need to replace one of my entities mapping file with a different one.  How can I do that?  I tried loading the assembly's mapping then adding the one I wanted replaced but that gave me an error.

Here is my mapping code:

```
    Configuration _configuration = new Configuration()
      .SetProperty(Environment.ReleaseConnections, "on_close")
      .SetProperty(Environment.Dialect, typeof (SQLiteDialect).AssemblyQualifiedName)
      .SetProperty(Environment.ConnectionDriver, typeof (SQLite20Driver).AssemblyQualifiedName)
      .SetProperty(Environment.ConnectionString, "data source=:memory:")
      .SetProperty(Environment.ProxyFactoryFactoryClass,
                   "NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle")
      .AddAssembly(assemblyContainingMapping);
    _sessionFactory = _configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
```

I want to be able to replace one entity mapping before I call BuildSessionFactory().

Comment: `_configuration.AddXml(File.ReadAllText("newmapping.hbm.xml"));` should just work

Comment: That will work for replacing an entity that is already added by the line .AddAssembly(assemblyContainingMapping)?

Comment: When I tried that I get the following error message.NHibernate.DuplicateMappingException : Duplicate class/entity mapping Opus3.Models.Activity

Comment: then you have to loop through the resources of the assembly manually and add all except that one. if you just want to change some details you can get the classmapping for that type and change the values

Comment: @Firo thanks for the help.  That worked.  Post looping through and modifying the entity as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the resources of the assembly manually and add all except that one.

If you just want to change some details you can get the classmapping for that type and change the values.

var mapping = config.GetMapping(typeof(myclass))
// change details of mapping